# L298N minimum output current/voltage

Tags: driver, stepper-driver

Does the L298N have a minimum output voltage? I want to control it such that the output varies from -Vs to +Vs, does it go linearly near 0, or is there a threshold that it passes? I can't tell what value I am supposed to read from the data sheet.

So far it seems that it drops to 0V after reaching .66V, but this might just be my multimeter playing up.

Comment: This is mentioned in the datasheet of the LN298 so why are you asking here?

Comment: Please post data sheet links when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

The L298N has two H-bridges in it, which are either connected to Vcc or ground (depending on what the input is).
The minimum voltage is ViH+2.5V. The minimum ViH voltage is 2.3. So the minimum output voltage would be 4.8V for Vcc.

When switched low the bridge will be slightly above ground because of the transistors, which will be the saturation voltage found in figure 1. This voltage is dependent on the current and won't go to zero because of the voltage across the low side transistor. So yeah you should be measuring a small voltage across the load on the out pin.

[image]
Source: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/82/cc/3f/39/0a/29/4d/f0/CD00000240.pdf/files/CD00000240.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000240.pdf

Comment: Ah unfortunate. Looks like I will need to either deal with that or find another component that does what I want.